# Wie ist "pragmatisch" konnotiert?

Tags: connotation

Der Duden beschreibt "pragmatisch" (u.a.) mit

> auf die anstehende Sache und entsprechendes praktisches Handeln gerichtet; sachbezogen

und mit folgenden Synonymen:

> anwendungsbezogen, den Erfahrungen entsprechend, handlungsbezogen, ideologiefrei, lösungsorientiert, sachbezogen

Für mich klingt "pragmatisch" daher sehr positiv konnotiert. Jedoch habe ich oft den Eindruck, dass andere Muttersprachler "pragmatisch" eher mit einem negativen Beigeschmack benutzen. Welche Bedeutung entgeht mir dabei?

Comment: Wie immer hängt das völlig vom Kontext ab... Vielleicht magst Du uns ein Beispiel geben, in dem solch ein bitterer Beigeschmack vermutet wird?

Comment: Ein "pragmatischer Innovationsbeauftragter" oder ein "pragmatischer Konservativer" sind sicher zwei sehr verschiedene Dinge.

Comment: @tofro Wieso, was ist der Unterschied?

Comment: Von einem "Innovationsbeauftragten" erwartet man eben nicht, dass er pragmatisch (handlungsbezogen), sondern innovativ (visionär) ist.

Comment: @Takkat Ich habe beispielsweise einen Nachbarn abschätzig über einen anderen Nachbarn sagen hören "Das ist doch so ein pragmatischer!". Keiner der beiden ist politisch aktiv.

Comment: @tofro   Ich sehe keinen großen Unterschied zwischen *pragmatischer Konservativer* und *pragmatischer Innovationsbeauftragter* (oder von mir aus auch: *pragmatischer Revolutionär*). *Pragmatisch* heißt in allen Fällen, dass die Person geneigt oder in der Lage ist, von der strengen Lehre zugunsten einer alltagsrealistischen Konzilianz abzuweichen und fünfe auch mal grade sein zu lassen. Dass weder Konservative noch Innovationsbegeisterte oder Revolutionäre regelmäßig mit so viel Pragmatismus glänzen, wie der gemeine Alltagsschluffi, ist eine andere Frage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Negative Konnotationen können enstehen, wo der Pragmatismus mit anderen Zielsetzungen in Konflikt steht.

Zum Beispiel kann man einer pragmatischen Lösung vorwerfen, dass sie nicht den Prinzipien und Idealen einer Organisation (oder auch den eigenen) entspricht. In der Politik zum Beispiel werden Mitglieder von Parteien häufig einem ideologischen Flügel oder dem pragmatischen (kompromissbereiten) Flügel zugerechnet. Dort erntet die kompromissbereite Seite dann manchmal Kritik für ihren Pragmatismus.

In Unternehmen werden pragmatische Lösungen teilweise auch nicht gern gesehen, wenn sie Verfahrensregeln und festgelegte Prozeduren missachten. Wer etwas "auf dem kurzen Dienstweg regelt" (das heißt im direkten Gespräch und nicht über die entsprechende Hierarchie) handelt zwar pragmatisch, kann aber auch für die Missachtung von Arbeitsvorschriften ermahnt werden.

Comment: Danke! Der Absatz über Unternehmen war sehr hilfreich.